# ga:adCost not working with ga:source different than google

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

from approx a month Analytics API not showing data for imported adCost. This data are visible in Analytics as Cost in standard report called Cost Analysis. Data in spreadsheet addon which I'm using just disappeared.

---

**adCost working with parameters:**

metrics: ga:adCost

filters: ga:source==google

---

**adCost working with parameters**

metrics: ga:adCost

filters: ga:source empty */just not using in this case*

---

**adCost not working with parameters**

metrics: ga:adCost

filters: ga:source==ceneo */or any different source*

---

This is same problem on google analytics spreadsheet addon and  https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

How can I track this kind of problem?

-------------------edit
I will show you on photosh how it looks:
[same data from Cost Analysis Report and Query Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI4Df.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any code snippet and error logs so we could replicate and somehow get a solution based on what we will find?

Comment: I'm just using spreadsheet-api, there is no error logs, just report status "completed successfully" with 0 - zeros on adCsot column. It looks like API not recognizes ga:source filter.

Comment: ga:sourceMedium==ceneo / cpc working properly but using just source shows "0".